# Referencing a local heading when using autosectionlabel

Tags: python-sphinx

How do I reference a subsection heading within a local document with sphinx when I have autosectionlabel and autosectionlabel_prefix_document enabled. I have a detailed and rather nested folder arrangement of my documentation and would like to replace the long path with something which represent the local file. #,  . or the local filename doesn't work

example

```
Heading 1
---------

subheading
^^^^^^^^^^

:ref:`/full/path/relative_to_config_file:subheading` works
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate a list of all headings which are within the sphinx document framework so I can see what is/isn't missing?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [`autosectionlabel`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html) are not altogether clear to me.  I think you can do what you want without the absolute reference:

```
Heading 1
---------

subheading
^^^^^^^^^^

:ref:`relative/to/config/file:subheading`
```

Or perhaps:

```
:ref:`relative-to-config-file:subheading`
```

Otherwise you would have to use arbitrary [cross-references](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role).

> If you place a label directly before a section title, you can reference to it with :ref:`label-name`. For example:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```

Comment: This makes the point of autosectionlabeling redundant as you have to label every section (again) to use it

Comment: if I use the full path name no, but everything else is  WARNING: undefined label

Comment: Sometimes full path names generate the warnings

Comment: Please provide the complete warnings by editing your answer. I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way is to use html style links
e.g.

```
`Text to display instead of subheading <#subheading>`_
```

Comment: Remember spaces are converted to hyphens

Comment: Does this work in pdf output? Might be the best solution if so